# Jquery, looping over a json array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops

I am getting the following JSON string from a webservice.

```
[{"TITLE":"asdasdasd","DESCRIPTION":"asdasd","PORTFOLIOID":1},
 {"TITLE":"sss","DESCRIPTION":"sss","PORTFOLIOID":2},
 {"TITLE":"sdfsdf","DESCRIPTION":"sdfsfsdf","PORTFOLIOID":3}]
```

Can i loop over this array in jquery and output the individual key/value pairs?

Comment: And the answer is: Yes you can!

Comment: Great, Care to let me kow how?

Comment: simple question, simple answer :)

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  Assuming you're telling jQuery to evaluate this response as JSON with the AJAX methods, you'd simply do this:

```
<script>
$(data).each(function(idx, obj) //this loops the array
{
    $(obj).each(function(key, value) //this loops the attributes of the object
    {
        console.log(key + ": " + value);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = [{"TITLE":"asdasdasd","DESCRIPTION":"asdasd","PORTFOLIOID":1}, ....]

$(a).each(function(index)
{
   //this is the object in the array, index is the index of the object in the array
   alert(this.TITLE + ' ' this.DESCRIPTION)
});
```

Check out the jQuery docs for more info... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/