# looping over a json object array with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Im trying to loop through a json files' object array to access its variables' keys and values and append them to list items using jquery's getjson and each.

I think the solution should be similar to the solution in this article... but I cant seem to make it work and display the results at all... Any help would be very much appreciated!

[Jquery, looping over a json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912037/jquery-looping-over-a-json-array)

```
$.getJSON('data/file.json', function(data)
 { 
   var data = [];
   $(data).each(function(idx, obj)
    { 
     $(obj).each(function(key, value)
      {console.log(key + ": " + value);}
     }
   }
);
```

The json data is formatted like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Name",
    "street_address1": "XYZ Road",
    "street_address2": null,
    "city": "New York",
    "zip": 10038,
    "phone": 2122222222 ", 
    "description ": "About xyz..."
 }, 
 { next listing... }]
```

And the html should be formatted like this:

```
 Name: Name

 Address: XYZ Road
          Floor #2
          City, State 10001

 Description: About xyz...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`var data = [];`

You are replacing `data` with a blank array, thus destroying your data when this is ran.  Remove this line, and it should work.

**EDIT**: There are also some syntax errors in your code.  You need to close the parenthesis after each of the `each` statements.  It should look like this:

```
$.getJSON('data/file.json', function(data){ 
    $(data).each(function(idx, obj){ 
        $(obj).each(function(key, value){
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2**: `data` and `obj` aren't jQuery objects, they are just normal objects.  You need to use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) compared to [`$().each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for this.

```
$.getJSON('data/file.json', function(data){ 
    $.each(data, function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Removed that and still nothing displays...?

Comment: @obj-ified: That's weird.  There's nothing in your console?

Comment: Hmm -- was getting 'missing paren after argument list in firebug console. I think the each callback functions werent being properly closed. I modified it -- but am now getting a listing of undefined objects --

Comment: @obj-ified: `data` and `obj` aren't jQuery objects, try using `$.each` instead of `$().each`.  Check the 2nd edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('data/file.json', function(data){ 
    $.each(data,function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `obj` isn't a jQuery object, you want to use `$.each` on that too.

Comment: Using `$(obj)` will actually wrap the object in an array, which will not help here.