# How to loop through Json data to retrieve value In Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Hii Guys!!!.
            I have a grid which is populating through jason data.Now I want to retrieve the
jason values using jquery ajax call from server side code...

Below is my server side code...

getGriddahico.ashx

```
                        string json ="";
                        json = json + "{\n";
                        json = json + " \"page\":\""+intpage+"\",\n";
                        json = json + "\"total\":"+total_pages+",\n";
                        json = json + "\"records\":"+total+",\n";
                        json = json + "\"rows\": [";
                        rc = false;

                        while(rs.Read()){

                            if(rc){
                                json = json + ",";
                            }
                            json = json + "\n{";
                            json = json + "\"price\":\"" + Convert.ToInt32(rs["price"]) + "\",";
                            json = json + "\"cell\":[" + Convert.ToInt32(rs["price"]) + "";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["username"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["ordinal"]) + "\"";
                            json = json + ",\"" + Convert.ToString(rs["toc"]) + "\"]";
                            json = json + "}";

                            rc=true;
                        }
                        json = json +"]\n";

                        json = json +"}";
```

and Here is my Jquery Ajax Call  code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('getGriddahico.ashx', function (data) {
            //loop thru  json data
            //data will contain  json values < --
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                console.log(val);
            });
        });
    });
```

Plz guys Help me how to retrive the value from server side datareader to client side variable..
Thanx in advance.

Comment: what you have written in you `getGriddahico.ashx`? Please post it.

Comment: @krshekhar sir server side code is the 'getGriddahico.ashx'

Comment: what is `rs.Read()` is it a data reader (reading data from database)?

Comment: @krshekhar yes Sir..it is datareader from database

Comment: @vikas I suggest you to use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.71).aspx) instead of concatenating strings

Comment: can you post the whole code of you handler. Are you getting the correct json from there?

Comment: @krshekhar yes sir i am getting correct json from there and relevent code was that much only in handler

Comment: @vikas put alert("") and see what is coming in alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks as though you are returning a string value which you need to then parse in the JavaScript into a json object.

Use the code [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('getGriddahico.ashx', function (data) {

    /* convert to json object */
    var json $.parseJSON(data);

    //loop thru  json data
    //data will contain  json values
    $.each(json, function (key, val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why some one will have to parse a json into a json? If the content type is json.

Comment: How are you returning the json string from getGriddahico.ashx ?

Comment: @TimBJames by using  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);

Comment: @vikas and what is the `context.Response.ContentType`

Comment: @krshekhar sir it is '"text/plain";'

Comment: it should be `context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";` as you are returning json from your handler

Comment: @krshekhar ok Sir i have changed it to 'application/json'

Comment: @vikas now what are you getting in the console. or alert inside loop?

Comment: @krshekhar Sir I am getting only the first value of json string "-2147483648"

Comment: @krshekhar Sir Now it is reading values before the datareader while loop one by one

Comment: @krshekhar '-2147483648
-2147483648
150508
[]'  this is the console values sir

Answer (score 0):

as you are getting `-2147483648 -2147483648 150508 []` the fourth one `([])` is an array.

 so you will have to loop again for getting values from the inner array.

You need multiple loop for the same. I think below should work. 
In the first loop you will get the values which are not array
and In the inner loop you will get the array values.

Values of `page`,`total` and `records` in the first loop

 and in the inner loop you will get `price` and `cell`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('getGriddahico.ashx', function (data){ 
        $.each(data, function(idx, obj){ 
           $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                console.log(key + ": " + value);
           });
    });
});
```

You can refer this link

[looping over a json object array with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191646/looping-over-a-json-object-array-with-jquery)

Comment: @krshekar Thnx sir for ur response but here also I am getting only random values like 0:- 1:2 2:1 3:4 etc

Comment: can you put your json created by c#

Comment: @krshekar Here is my json values Sir... {
 "page":"1",
"total":1506,
"records":150508,
"rows": [
{"price":"0","cell":[0,"","3011","0","3011","9999","1784","6/13/2011 12:00:00 AM","1/1/1900 1:22:17 PM","63","","0","INTERNAL"]},
{"price":"0","cell":[0,"","1229","0","1229","9999","1255","6/13/2011 12:00:00 AM","1/1/1900 1:26:23 PM","2","","0","INTERNAL"]}]
}

Comment: what do you want to do with these values?

Comment: These values are generated at server i want to retrieve these values to .aspx client page..by jquery url call

Comment: I mean what do you want to do with these values display some where in the page ?