# How do I loop over a JSON Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have the following JSON structure: -

```
Afghanistan
    : { latitude: "33.93911", longitude: "67.709953" }
American Samoa
    : { latitude: "-14.270972", longitude: "-170.132217" }
Australia
    : { latitude: "-25.274398", longitude: "133.775136" }
```

How do I loop through it using Javascript or Jquery and get all the **values** like **Australia, latitude, longitude** etc?

I am creating above JSON format from **json_encode** function in PHP.

Here is the original Array format from which I am creating JSON format: -

```
array (size=94)
  'India' => 
    array (size=2)
      'latitude' => string '20.593684' (length=9)
      'longitude' => string '78.96288' (length=8)
  'Pakistan' => 
    array (size=2)
      'latitude' => string '30.375321' (length=9)
      'longitude' => string '69.345116' (length=9)
```

Comment: use `.each()` to loop it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looping over a json object array with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191646/looping-over-a-json-object-array-with-jquery)

Comment: @guradio can you please elaborate more or give me any working example on how to use .each loop to get all values like country name, latitude, longitude etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JS code after fixing your JSON with quotes and commas:

```js
var countries = {
  "Afghanistan": {
    "latitude": "33.93911",
    "longitude": "67.709953"
  },
  "American Samoa": {
    "latitude": "-14.270972",
    "longitude": "-170.132217"
  },
  "Australia": {
    "latitude": "-25.274398",
    "longitude": "133.775136"
  }
}
for (var country in countries) {
  values = countries[country];
  console.log('Country: ', country);
  console.log('Latitude: ', values.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ', values.longitude);
}
```

Comment: How I fix my JSON to use your code?? Because my values are dynamic and I am getting values through Ajax. Right I have more than 20 entries in my JSON. How I fixed that?

Comment: You don't need to fix anything if you receive the JSON data from an AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `var countries` holding your **AJAX** response **country** `JSON`. Use below code to solve your problem::

```js
var countries = {
 "Afghanistan": {
  "latitude": "33.93911",
  "longitude": "67.709953"
 },
 "American Samoa": {
  "latitude": "-14.270972",
  "longitude": "-170.132217"
 },
 "Australia": {
  "latitude": "-25.274398",
  "longitude": "133.775136"
 }
}
$.each(countries, function (index, value) {
 console.log("Country=>" + index + ", Latitude=>" + value.latitude + ", Longitude=>" + value.longitude);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can I talk to you on chat?

Comment: @junaidafzal yap why not.

Comment: @RanaGosh I am not seeing any chat link on your profile?