# loop a recieved json string to get values by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse data returned from `$.post()`.

```
[{"id":"1","text":"USD"},
 {"id":"2","text":"CNY"},
 {"id":"3","text":"PHP"},
 {"id":"4","text":"AUD"},
 {"id":"5","text":"SGD"},
 {"id":"6","text":"JPY"}]
```

using this approach [Jquery, looping over a json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912037/jquery-looping-over-a-json-array)

I did something like this:

```
$.post(
    base_url+'cgame/currency',
    { gameID: gameID },
    function(data) {
        $(this).html();
        $.each(data,function(idx, obj) {
            $(obj).each(function(key, value) {
                console.log(key + ": " + value);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

but it gives me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '120' in `[{"id":"2","text":"CNY"},{"id":"3","text":"PHP"},{"id":"4","text":"AUD"},{"id":"5","text":"SGD"},{"id":"6","text":"JPY"}]`

I also tried:

```
$.post(
    base_url+'cgame/currency',
    { gameID: gameID },
    function(data) {
        $(this).html();
        $(data).each(function(idx, obj) {
            $(obj).each(function(key, value) {
                console.log(key + ": " + value);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

but it also gives me the error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `[{"id":"1","text":"USD"},{"id":"6","text":"JPY"}]`

How should I be doing this?

Comment: I guess you need to parse the JSON-string (data) to a JSON object before you iterate over it. Try JSON.parse(data) and iterate over that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function(data) {
    var value = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(value ,function(idx, obj) {
       console.log("id : "+obj.id+" "+text:"+obj.text);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data comes in the form of array so you need to loop through each index and then fetch the values. So you can replace this :-

```
 $(obj).each(function(key, value) {
     console.log(key + ": " + value);
 });
```

with :-

```
 $.each( obj, function( key) {
     console.log( obj[key].id + ':' + obj[key].text);
 });
```

or you can do this :-

```
 $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
     console.log( value.id + ':' + value.text);
 });
```

key is the index of array. It will return 0,1,2..

Comment: yeah, thanks.. your second answer was also the thing i've found out from eggward and fibbe suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the argument passed to your success callback function is of type string. Change it to:

```
 function(data) {
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    $(this).html();
    $.each(parsedData ,function(idx, obj) {
        $(obj).each(function(key, value) {
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your effort :D ive already found the answer based on yours and the comment above my post.

Comment: this gives the output of 0: [object Object] grid.js:159
0: [object Object] grid.js:159
0: [object Object] grid.js:159
0: [object Object] grid.js:159
0: [object Object] grid.js:159
0: [object Object]. There is no error bu still values are not cuaght properly. So what i did is to remove the second loop of your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.post(base_url+'cgame/currency',{ gameID: gameID },
 function(data) {
    $(this).html(); //<-- becareful $(this) might not be the element you think it is
    $.each(data,function(idx, obj) {
        console.log( "id : " + obj.id);
        console.log( "text: " + obj.text);
   });
 },'JSON');
```

Comment: im sorry but still gives the second error on my post.but thanks for the help :D